# zero composition for bounded linear map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $V$. Assume that for every $v \in V$ there exists a **non-negative** integer such that $T^n (v) = 0$. Prove that there exists an **integer** $n$ such that $T^n (v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Tought: Seems like it is related to Baire Category theorem but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: The space $V_n = \text{ker}(T^n)$ is closed and $V = \bigcup_n V_n$. Then use Baire's theorem to conclude.

Comment: The statement crucially relies on the Baire category theorem. For general normed spaces the statement is false. Consider the left shift on $c_{00}$ (sequences in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ with only finitely many non-zero entries).

Comment: Can you elaborate your first comment please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly shorter answer can be found here [Power of a bounded linear map nullify each point implies the power is eventually zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684331/power-of-a-bounded-linear-map-nullify-each-point-implies-the-power-is-eventually?rq=1). I have spelled out the details in a bit more details.

We start by defining for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$V_n = \text{ker}(T^n). $$

As the composition of continuous maps is continuous, we get that $V_n=(T^n)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Furthermore, we are assuming that for every $v\in V$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T^n(v)=0$ (which implies $v\in V_n$). Thus, we have

$$ V= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} V_n. $$

Now, by Baire's theorem, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V_N$ has nonempty interior (if you know Baire's theorem only for open sets, this [Equivalence of Baire Category Theorem for Complete Metric Spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007669/equivalence-of-baire-category-theorem-for-complete-metric-spaces) might be helpful). However, $V_N$ is a linear space and therefore $V_N=V$. To see this last statement, we note that the map $F_a:V\rightarrow V, x\mapsto x-a$ is an homeomorphism for every $a\in V$. If $a$ is in the interior of $V_N$, then $0$ is an interior point of $V_N = F_a(V_N)$. Thus, $V_N$ contains a ball around the origin, i.e. $B_\varepsilon(0)\subseteq V_N$. However, $V_N$ is a linear space, thus, for all $R\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $B_{R\varepsilon}(0)\subseteq R V_N = V_N$ and hence $V_N=V$.

Note that the requirement that $V$ is a Banach space is crucial. The statement is no longer true for general normed space. Consider the space
$$ c_{00} = \left\{ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}) \ : \ \text{ only finitely many entries are nonzero} \right\} $$
with the supremum norm and the left-shift
$$ T: c_{00} \rightarrow c_{00}, (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots) \mapsto (a_2, a_3, a_4, \dots). $$
By definition every element of $c_{00}$ is of the form $v=(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m, 0, 0, \dots)$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $T^m(v)=0$. However, there is no $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T^N$ is the zero map (consider elements of the form $(1,1, \dots, 1, 0,0,0, \dots)$).